# Is indigo haram in islam

Tags: halal-haram

I just wanted to know that indigo is haram in islam. Because it has same texture  as henna and it also works like henna but it is blue in color. Unlike henna indigo releases blue color naturally on hairs it shines like dark blue. And most of the pople blends henna powder with indigo powder to get darker stain. Because of its blue color i wanted to ask that is it haram or hot

Answer (score -1):

[Bukhari, narrated by Anas bin Malik](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/63/146)

> When the Prophet (ﷺ) arrived at Medina, the eldest amongst his
>   companions was Abu Bakr. He dyed his hair with Hinna and Katam till it
>   became of dark red color.

KATAM is Indigo.

Black is not allowed, or any other odd  color like blue, purple etc.

By using Indigo only will make color blue so mix it with Hinna.

Hope it will help

Comment: -1 There is no relation between the Hadith you quoted and the claim you made.

Comment: @Aboudi Can you please provide the detail what is KATAM? and how it is not related?

Comment: Katam is not indigo. Katam is Buxus Dioica  and indigo is Indigofera tinctoria

Comment: Both are a kind of plant leaf, so what is the difference? See the image of  buxus dioica leaf or indigo leaf